# Value of constants in Big Theta notation

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

In Big Theta notation, do the constants `c1` and `c2` differ for each value of `n`?.

**Definition:**

```
Theta(g(n)) = {f(n): there exist c1 >= 0, c2 > 0 and n0 > 0
                     such that for all n >= n0,
                     0 <= c1, g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 * g(n)}
```

Comment: This is maths only, not good on SO.

Comment: This might be better posted on the Theoretical Computer Science StackExchange: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think the constants are for each function `f`. A function `f` is in that set iff there exist `c1`, `c2` and `n0` s.t. `0 <= c1`, `g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 * g(n)` for all `n >= n0`.

Answer (score 4):

`c1` and `c2` are not different for each value of `n`. If they were, they would be dependent on `n`, and wouldn't be constants.

Comment: If there are three functions n, n^2 and n^3 and for each value of n in the function n^2, we have the functions n and n^3 differing by a constant proportion..Do we refer to these as the constants c1 and c2??

Comment: But `n` and `n^3` aren't different by a constant; for any constant `c`, `cn < n^3` for some value of `n`.

Comment: Yes, I am getting that n and n^3 aren't different by a constant. However, I am not able to grasp your idea about the constants. Can you please be more detail and also give an example?

Comment: @sai constants defined here are nothing but some fixed real value which will not vary with n. For any n these constants will remain same.

Comment: Well, say that `c1` was allowed to vary for different values of `n`. Let's say it varies so that when `n = 2`, `c1 = 4`, and when `n = 3`, `c1 = 9`. In fact, let's have `c1` always equal to `n^2`; that makes `c1*n = n^3`. But we know that "`n` and `n^3` aren't different by a constant." See the problem with having `c1` and `c2` vary?

Answer (score 1):

```
Theta(g(n)) = {f(n): for all n >= n0, there exist c1 >= 0, c2 > 0 and n0 > 0
                 such that 0 <= c1, g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 * g(n)}
```

I don't think the quantifiers in your definition are correct.  It should be

```
Theta(g(n)) = {f(n): there exist c1 >= 0, c2 > 0 and n0 > 0
                 such that for all n >= n0, c1 * g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 * g(n)}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. It should be fixed now.